# PHP not removing escape slashes

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am returning data from a PHP file that contains escape slashes that need to be removed.

I created a return object that is a multidimensional array. I am returning it with `json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`, but the slashes are not being removed.

I have also tried different methods that involve looping though each individual string in the arrays using `stripslashes()` and even that didn't work.

I am having no trouble getting the desired data to return in the correct JSON structure, but I cannot seem to get rid of these slashes!

```
$data = array('bodyCopy' => array(), 'projects' => array());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data['bodyCopy'] = $row;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM experienceSectionProjects";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($data['projects'], $row);
}

echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

My return object loos like this:

**EDIT**
Here is some real data that contains the slashes:

```
    {
    "bodyCopy":{
    "title":"Experience's",
    "headerIcon":"briefcase",
    "introCopy":"Don't",
    "gridHeader":"header"
    },
    "projects":[
    {
     "id":"1",
     "company":"Medical Mutual",
     "position":"UI Developer",
     "logo":"medmutual.png",
     "backgroundImg":"medMutual.jpg",
     "projectSummary":"Online enrollment application for health insurance marketplace",
     "description":"I work as the dedicated front end developer on the online enrollment application for the Medical Mutual Individual Insurance Marketplace and Medicare Advantage Marketplace. As front end developer my main responsibility is generating HTML/CSS/JS for the users interface. I collaborate with server side developers in an C#.NET MVC environment to create dynamic content and integrate the code from the UI into Sitecore. Aside from the Online Enrollment applications, I am involved with developing other public facing websites for the company including an internal recruitment website."
    },
    {
     "id":"2",
     "company":"Macy\'s",
     "position":"UI/AngularJS Developer",
     "logo":"macys.png",
     "backgroundImg":"macys.jpg",
     "projectSummary":"CRM software for in store sales associates",
     "description":""
    }
 ]
}
```

**EDIT**

This may give more info. This is how I am writing values to the database:

```
    $projects = $p['projects'];
    if(is_array($projects)) {
        foreach ($projects as $project) {

            $id = $project['id'];
            $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $project['company']);
            $position = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $project['position']);
            $logo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $project['logo']);
            $backgroundImg = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $project['backgroundImg']);
            $projectSummary = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $project['projectSummary']);
            $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $project['description']);

            $Query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO experienceSectionProjects (id, company, position, logo, backgroundImg, projectSummary, description)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE company = VALUES(company), position = VALUES(position), logo = VALUES(logo), backgroundImg = VALUES(backgroundImg), projectSummary = VALUES(projectSummary), description = VALUES(description)");
            $Query->bind_param('issssss', $id, $company, $position, $logo, $backgroundImg, $projectSummary, $description);
            $Query->execute();
            $Query->close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you see slashes here?

Comment: I removed the real data for readability because I didn't think it would matter, but I will add in some real data if you think it wi help you

Comment: Did you verify that constant is what you think it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` adds slashes to the string so that when you put it in an SQL query, special characters won't be treated as special characters.

`bind_param` passes variables to a prepared statement *without putting them  directly in the SQL statement*.

Do one or the other (hint: `bind_param` is saner) **not both**.

Answer (score 3):

Replace all the lines containing `mysqli_real_escape_string()` with this ...

```
$company = $project['company'];
$position = $project['position'];
$logo = $project['logo'];
$backgroundImg = $project['backgroundImg'];
$projectSummary = $project['projectSummary'];
$description = $project['description'];
```

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` adds slashes where required in order that a raw query doesn't fall over. You are already using prepared statements which binds the variables after preparing the raw query, so that is not required.

Comment: Thanks this did it! I had to give the first answer the green checkmark though he beat you by a few minutes